# Shell starts in incorrect directory in OS X Lion Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion

In OS X Lion, when I launch a new tab in the Terminal with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, the shell starts in the `/` directory.

```
$ pwd
/
```

Comment: On a vanilla unix system I would be instantly suspicious that you were logging in as root. I've never tried that on a Mac OS box, but if you I would advise you to quit doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually how the new tab is opened relies on the settings in terminal.

The *New tabs open with:* setting should read however you would like the default behavior to be. I'm guessing you should switch this to *Default Working Directory* (opposite of what I have selected below).

If you're having issues where you want the same directory that you're working in to open, you may need to adjust some of your terminal environmental settings.

[image]